# How do I test external user functions in the sandbox

Tags: visualforce, community

I'm getting this error when trying to login or create an external user in a Salesforce Community site:

That operation is only allowed from within an active site.

From what I've read, this is because Site functions are only available to external users, not those logged in internally. But I am in the sandbox environment and must login to get to any of my visualforce pages. How am I able to test these pages while logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an easy one - I just had to access the page using the external URL.